# Spring, Tomcat 8 Ehcache replication across AWS cluster(on EC2 instanse)

Tags: spring, tomcat, amazon-web-services, replication, ehcache

In my Spring application I use a following cache(`ehcache`):

```
<bean id="statelessTicketCache"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.EhCacheBasedTicketCache">
        <property name="cache">
            <bean id="ehcache" class="net.sf.ehcache.Cache" init-method="initialise"
                destroy-method="dispose">
                <constructor-arg value="casTickets" />
                <constructor-arg value="0" />
                <constructor-arg value="true" />
                <constructor-arg value="false" />
                <constructor-arg value="3600" />
                <constructor-arg value="900" />
                <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In this cache I'm storing access tickets to my API back end. Everything works perfectly with a single node Tomcat8. But when I try to use 2 or more instances in my AWS cluster with Load Balancer(ELB) and N Tomcats(on EC2 instances) I ran into the issue that each node operates with own instance of `statelessTicketCache`.

I need to replicate this `ehcache statelessTicketCache` across my cluster. Is it possible ? If so, could you please provide a sample configuration for this ?

**UPDATED**

I think, I'll move out from the `Ehcache` solution and will try to configure `statelessTicketCache` with `Redis`(`AWS Elastic cache` on Redis engine) and use a following implementation https://github.com/vnomics/spring-stateless-ticket-cache-redis of Spring CAS Stateless Ticket Cache Redis

Answer (score 1):

I have moved out from the Ehcache solution and configured `statelessTicketCache` with Redis(AWS Elastic cache on Redis engine) with a following implementation https://github.com/vnomics/spring-stateless-ticket-cache-redis of Spring CAS Stateless Ticket Cache Redis.

Now, everything works fine.